# How to find all .js files which import a particular .js file in a React-App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a react application .i have the following file : (I am using VSCode)

```
#example .js 
export default helloWorld =()=>{
    return  "Hello World" ;
```

Is there a way , i can  look for all the .js files which imports this  file ?.
I understand different files can have this function by the same name  . 
So is there a way we can look which files have used something like  :

```
import helloWorld from "somevariablePath/example.js"
```

Comment: Simply search the folder with sources for `example.js`. Use [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) - the friendliest code editor these days.

Comment: Can you elaborate more ? Do you mean manual look-up ?

Comment: You said you want to look them up, so - yes I mean manual. And by manual I mean through the search feature of any code editor. Consider to clarify your question if you meant something different.

Comment: Without any IDE? That is a common feature of IDEs

Comment: Apologies for confusion,i meant to say if  i can find all files which imported a particular file/ I have got quite a big project with quite a lot of files. So manual look up is indeed not a good idea for this case.

Comment: @Rashomon . Forgot to mention ..I am using vscode , and i dont know how to do that in vscode.

Answer (score 1):

try show all references or find all ref

[image]

Comment: I tried "Find all references" earlier ,but it just looks up for a certain item in the particular file in which it is located. So for example,in the OP if i select the function "helloWorld " then right click and then select "Find all references " it would just look for all references of the helloWorld  function in the example.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently, and realized theres not a perfect solution for this. The CommonJS modules aren't well-suited for static analysis.

Anyway, I found useful following tools:

**JetBrains Webstorm IDE (Premium)**

The feature *Find Usages* from this IDE is the most accurate tool I found. But its a paid IDE. (You have a 30 days trial period)

**VSCode**

The feature *Find all references* is not as accurate as previous one, but still useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured  out an easy way to do that in the VSCode. 
If i just use the absolute path (the absolute path can of course be shortened by using `NODE_PATH` environment variable in the .env file)  of the file which i want to track(see whereever it is imported) . 
I can just copy the path  , do a `Ctrl+Shift+F` ,paste the path in the search bar and press Enter(Pressing Enter is important). 
This will give all the files where that particular line of code ,in this case , `import helloWorld from "absolutePath/example.js`,is used

Answer (score -2):

checkout dynamic import feature of webpack if fits yours requirement .

[Dynamic import](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import)

or iterate using the file system(fs module) and load the file based on your condition

Comment: This is not what OP is asking